# ASP.Net Core BackgroundService is cancelled without reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I developed a BackgroundService, at the beginning it works Ok. But later at 20 minutes this is cancelled for some reason that I don't know.
For this case in particular, the "job" should be infinite and never finish. Please, could  you give some idea ? I'll appreciate it

```
public class CheckItemsService : BackgroundService
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public CheckItemsService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.Register(() => Log.Information("Job is stopping"));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await UpdateItems();

            await Task.Delay(1000 * 60, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateItems()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WalletContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:Default").Value);
        DbContext _context = new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

        var items = await _context.EntityX.ToListAsync();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException dbEx)
        {
            Log.Information(dbEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `StopAsync(CancellationToken)` called, override that method and have it log if it is. If so it means the host is shutting down for some reason.

Comment: If you’re hosting this on IIS for example, it could be the default app pool iddle time that causes it to shutdown because it wouldn’t take your background service into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Scott Chamberlain Thanks man, in base on your comment you gave me the idea of searching why the host was shutting down, so I figured out that IIS has a default configuration for "inactivity" in every site for 20 minutes. I changed this and it's working perfectly.
@Vidmantas Blazevicius Thanks so much man, indeed this was the reason of my problem. Appreciate it for your help.

Link where I find the solution of the configuration on IIS → [How to prevent IIS from shutting down Web Site when not in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993968/how-to-prevent-iis-from-shutting-down-web-site-when-not-in-use)